# tkinter show frames after a delay

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to make a GUI with 3 pages. The start page has a title and a start button. When the start button was pressed, PageOne would be shown, after 5 seconds, PageTwo would shown.
However, now it is working in a different way: when clicking the button, the 5 seconds were waited with the start page stayed. Then PageOne and PageTwo were shown, which I was only able to see PageTwo.
Would someone tell me how can I fix the issue? Thanks a lot.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('{}x{}'.format(height, width))
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  

        self.frames = {}
        for f in [StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo]:
            self.frames[f] = f(self.container, self)
            self.frames[f].config(height=height)
            self.frames[f].config(width=width)
            self.frames[f].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, page):
        self.frames[page].tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self): 
        self.instruction = tk.Label(self, text='My Title')
        self.instruction.config(font=("Courier", 20))
        self.instruction.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text = 'START', command=self.click_start)
        self.button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    def click_start(self):
        # show PageOne
        self.controller.show_frame(PageOne)
        # wait for 5 seconds
        time.sleep(5)
        # show PageTwo
        self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self): 
        self.label = tk.Label(self,text='PageOne')
        self.label.config(font=("Courier", 20))
        self.label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4, anchor=tk.CENTER)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='PageTwo')
        self.label.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        self.label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    root = MyApp(height=500, width=500)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see your problem?

Comment: We can't run your code -- it depends on a class named `BestModel` which isn't part of what you posted. Please post _only_ what is necessary to reproduce the problem, but please post _everything_ that is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `after` widget method to schedule future events. The first argument is a number of milliseconds, the next argument is a reference to a function, and any additional arguments will be passed to the function.

```
def click_start(self):
    self.controller.show_frame(PageOne)
    self.controller.after(5000, self.controller.show_frame, PageTwo)
```